# K-means algorithm, R

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, k-means

everyone! I've been asked to create an K-means algorithm on R, but I don't really know the language, so I've found some example code on the internet, and decided to use. I've looked into it, learned the functions that are being used in it, and corrected it a bit, because it didn't work very well. Here's the code:

```
# Creating a sample of data
y=rnorm(500,1.65)
x=rnorm(500,1.15)
x=cbind(x,y)
centers <- x[sample(nrow(x),5),]

# A function for calculating the distance between centers and the rest of the dots
euclid <- function(points1, points2) {
  distanceMatrix <- matrix(NA, nrow=dim(points1)[1], ncol=dim(points2)[1])
  for(i in 1:nrow(points2)) {
    distanceMatrix[,i] <- sqrt(rowSums(t(t(points1)-points2[i,])^2))
  }
  distanceMatrix
}


# A method function
K_means <- function(x, centers, euclid, nItter) {
  clusterHistory <- vector(nItter, mode="list")
  centerHistory <- vector(nItter, mode="list")

  for(i in 1:nItter) {
    distsToCenters <- euclid(x, centers)
    clusters <- apply(distsToCenters, 1, which.min)
    centers <- apply(x, 2, tapply, clusters, mean)
    # Saving history
    clusterHistory[[i]] <- clusters
    centerHistory[[i]] <- centers
  }

  structure(list(clusters = clusterHistory, centers = centerHistory))

}


res <- K_means(x, centers, euclid, 5)
#To use the same plot operations I had to use unlist, since the resulting object in my function is a list of lists,
#and default object is just a list. And also i store the history of each iteration in that object.
res <- unlist(res, recursive = FALSE)
plot(x, col = res$clusters5)
points(res$centers5, col = 1:5, pch = 8, cex = 2)
```

It works fine on this simple matrix. But I've been asked to use it on iris:

```
head(iris)
a <-data.frame(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Petal.Length, iris$Petal.Width)
centers <- a[sample(nrow(a),3),]
iris_clusters <- K_means(a, centers, euclid, 3)
iris_clusters <- unlist(iris_clusters, recursive = FALSE)
head(iris_clusters)
```

And the problem is that it doesn't work. The error is:

```
Error in distanceMatrix[, i] <- sqrt(rowSums(t(t(points1) - points2[i,  : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I understand that dimensions of objects don't match, but I don't understand why. That's why i'm asking for help. I apologize for all the stupidity there may be in this code in advance, but I'm not really familiar with the language yet, so don't judge me too harsh. Thank you!

Comment: It may be because in your example `centers` is a matrix and with 'iris' is a data frame. try `centers <- unlist(a[sample(nrow(a),3),])`

Comment: Do you need to write your own or just produce a `kmeans` output? If it's the latter, `kmeans` is built in. Consider `kmeans(iris[, -5], 3)`.

Comment: That was quick! Thank you for the answer @PierreLafortune, but now it gives another error:  Error in matrix(NA, nrow = dim(points1)[1], ncol = dim(points2)[1]) : 
  non-numeric matrix extent 'code'

Comment: Yes, I have to write my own, @MichaelGriffiths And i know there's built-in one, checked it on iris to see the result i should get, if i would use my own algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation should work with simple typecasts

```
iris_clusters <- K_means(as.matrix(a), as.matrix(centers), euclid, 3) # 3 iterations

iris_clusters <- unlist(iris_clusters, recursive = FALSE)

# plotting the clusters obtained on the first two dimensions at the end of 3rd iteration

plot(a[,1:2], col = iris_clusters$clusters3, pch=19) 
points(iris_clusters$centers3, col = 1:5, pch = 8, cex = 2)
```

[image]

```
head(iris_clusters)

# cluster assignments and centroids computed at different iterations

$clusters1
  [1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 3
 [77] 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 2 1 2 1 1 3 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2

$clusters2
  [1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2
 [77] 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2

$clusters3
  [1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 [77] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2

$centers1
  iris.Sepal.Length iris.Sepal.Width iris.Petal.Length iris.Petal.Width
1          7.150000         3.120000          6.090000        2.1350000
2          6.315909         2.915909          5.059091        1.8000000
3          5.297674         3.115116          2.550000        0.6744186

$centers2
  iris.Sepal.Length iris.Sepal.Width iris.Petal.Length iris.Petal.Width
1          7.122727         3.113636          6.031818        2.1318182
2          6.123529         2.852941          4.741176        1.6132353
3          5.056667         3.268333          1.810000        0.3883333

$centers3
  iris.Sepal.Length iris.Sepal.Width iris.Petal.Length iris.Petal.Width
1          7.014815         3.096296          5.918519         2.155556
2          6.025714         2.805714          4.588571         1.518571
3          5.005660         3.369811          1.560377         0.290566
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, @sandipan. The result isn't perfect, because of the algorithm, I suppose, but it works!

Comment: @ John Dirak I think it has not converged yet with 3 iterations, we can try more iterations (e.g., 6) to get it converged. Also, we are projecting it on the first two dimensions only, ignoring the last two, but kmeans used all the 4, so there is expected to be some discrepancy with the perfect one.

Comment: I've added much more iterations, but it still doesn't converge well. Projecting also messes things up, yes, thank you.